# Binary to decimal without using parseInt

Tags: javascript, loops, binary, decimal

I am really stuck on making a function for JavaScript.

I know how to mentally do the math from binary to decimal but I do not know how write it out.
I am not able to use parse int or to string.

I am not asking anyone to do this for me I would just like some ideas on where to start.

```
function BintoDec(x)
{
var number = x
```

Any help is good help.
thanks in advance

EDIT

I was able to come up with this function but i end up getting 0 as my output.
Help!

```
function BinToDec(x) {
var result = 0;
var multiple = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
var digit = x[x.length - 1 - i];

if (digit == '1') {
result += multiple;
}
multiple *= 2;
}
return result;
}

print(BinToDec(101));
```

Comment: if you know how to do the math, then just translate it to Javascript. That's what programming is all about.

Comment: Please describe the algorithm as you understand it, and explain which parts you're having trouble figuring out how to program. Otherwise, it's hard to know where to start with ideas.

Comment: @Barmar I know that binary to decimal is based off base=2 and the exponent is based on the place the 1 or 0 is on for example 0011=3 cause 2^1 + 2^0= 3

Comment: So you write a loop that adds the digits multiplied by the power of 2.

Answer (score 4):

> **I am not asking anyone to do this for me I would just like some ideas
>   on where to start**

You can use this:-

```
var digit = parseInt(binary, 2);
```

Also check [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

**EDIT:-**(Didnt saw that you dont want to use parseInt)

You may try to loop through the string and try like this:-

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  r = r * 2 + (arr[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: he said he can't use `parseInt`

Comment: @Barmar:- Does that make it better?

Answer (score 0):

First write a checking and make sure all characters are 0 or 1, once this is done and validated, start looping backwards in the string and multiplying 2 to the power of the counter by the 0 or 1:

```
         "0100101010"
                  <-

            +2^0 x 0
           +2^1 x 1
...
```

if you really need to implemented your self.
or you can use :

```
var binary = "0100101010";
parseInt(binary, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like the following in the function body:

```
var dec = 0, char;
for (var i = x.length - 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    char = x.charAt(i);
    if (char) {
        dec += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you have dec = char? the char is whats making me confused

Comment: I've declared two variables, dec and char in the following line: `var dec = 0, char;` Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct and nicely formatted solution:

```
  function bin2dec(num){
    return num.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x, y, i){
      return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
    }, 0);
  }
```